# I have an issue with the DataLayer. It's grouping all events into a single pageview, and it's not capturing events as it should. How can I fix this?

Tags: google-datalayer

I have a webpage with my own code, apparently, I have an issue with the DataLayer. It's grouping all events into a single pageview, and it's not capturing events as it should. How can I fix this?

Fix, or have a recommendation to uptadate automated the capture of data no to put event manualy per boton o issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.